# Bug while retrieving elements from a csv in python

Tags: python, csv

I'm attempting to retrieve elements from a 31 integer-element csv using tensorflow/numpy's csv handling, and I'm getting a really weird error.  The CSV itself is all integer values and looks fine in excel and notepad.
When I print the csv untouched, like so

```
data_file = csv.reader(csv_file)
#data and target to be used after testing
data, target = [], []
for row in data_file:
  print(row)
  print(len(row))
```

I get results that I expected(i.e. `['1', '-1', '1', '-1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '-1', '-1', '1', '1', '-1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'], len=31`)
However, if I try to retrieve any elements from inside any row of the csv (with, say, `print(row[0])`, even from index 0, I get an `IndexError: list index out of range error`. Additionally, doing this converts all other rows into rows with no elements.
What's going on here, and how do I fix it?
(The overall problem is getting a dataset to work with tf.contrib.learn's framework, help with that would also be useful)

Comment: Can you post exactly what gets printed to your output?  (or at least the first few lines)

Comment: Good output:`['1', '-1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '-1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '-1', '1', '1', '0', '-1', '1', '-1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1']
31
['1', '-1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '-1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '-1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']
31
['1', '-1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '-1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '-1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1']
31`

Comment: The rest of the output is more of the same. (the 31 is the `print(len(row))` command)

Comment: How big is your file?

Comment: ~1500 lines?  I've been able to do other csv stuff to it in other programs(e.g. splitting it) with no trouble.

Comment: adding `if len(row)>0:
        print(row[0])`
seems to fix things.  I'm incredibly confused.  Something weird is happening with the compiler.

Comment: When do you do the `row[0]`?  Inside the loop? after?  The error means that `row` is `[]` at that point.

Comment: @LeorFishman It is very possible you have some blank lines in your csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax you've posted is perfectly okay. Since it is not clear what the exact trouble is, might I suggest an alternative that you could use only if you do not have too much data:

```
with open('csvfile.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    all_rows = csvfile.read().splitlines() # BAD! Creates a list in memory with your file data rather than a lazy file pointer. Use with caution
    csvreader = csv.reader(all_rows)
    for row in csvreader:
        print(row[0])
```

It'll create a reader out of a list containing the lines in the file.

---

#### Edit

After testing both my code and yours on the data you pasted, I'm quite sure you've a stray newline somewhere, and that's messing things up.

Add the `if len(row) > 0` inside your loop and try to forget this happened.

Comment: Same IndexError.

Comment: If it isn't too much of a problem, would you care to paste a few lines from your csv file into a pastebin paste and link it here?

Comment: Also, @LeorFishman, does your csv have an empty first row? That might be the cause. You'll need to skip the first row in that case.

Comment: No empty first row.  I'll paste a few lines from the CSV.

Comment: 1 0 -1 1 1 -1 -1 -1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 -1 1 1 0 -1 1 -1 1 -1 -1 -1 1 1 1 1 -1


-1 0 -1 1 -1 -1 -1 1 1 1 1 -1 -1 1 0 -1 -1 -1 0 1 1 1 1 1 -1 -1 1 1 -1 -1 -1
1 0 -1 1 1 -1 -1 1 1 1 1 -1 -1 1 1 -1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 -1 -1 1 1 0 1 -1.
1 1 1 1 1 -1 -1 -1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 -1 -1 -1 0 1 1 1 1 -1 -1 -1 1 1 -1 -1 -1


1 1 -1 1 1 -1 0 -1 1 1 1 -1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 -1 -1 1 1 1 -1 1 -1

Comment: @LeorFishman I'm stumped. Both my code and yours work without any issues for the data you pasted. I'm 99.9% sure you've a stray newline somewhere, and that's messing things up. Keep the `if` statement like you mentioned, and try to shrug it off. This sort of thing happens all the time.

Comment: Does sorta look like that, given that adding an if statement to check the length of a row before retrieving fixes things, but I don't see a newline.

Answer (score 0):

I recall having a similar problem, and although I never solved it precisely, I migrated to using Pandas and storing the csv data in a dataframe. It really trivializes loading csv data:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('CSVfilename')
```

Dataframes are much better to use for large datasets as well, as opposed to iterating over each element in many lists/arrays.

Comment: I'm pretty restricted to tensorflow's numpy stuff, sadly.  Otherwise I'd switch to pandas.

Comment: How are you moving from the `csv.reader` output to something that `tensorflow` can use?

Answer (score 0):

In `numpy`, I can easily load your pastebin file with:

```
In [279]: data = np.genfromtxt('stack44527012.csv',delimiter=',',dtype=int)
In [280]: data.shape
Out[280]: (32, 31)
In [281]: data[:5,:]
Out[281]: 
array([[ 1,  0, -1,  1,  1, -1, -1, -1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0, -1,  1,
         1,  0, -1,  1, -1,  1, -1, -1, -1,  1,  1,  1,  1, -1],
       [-1,  0, -1,  1, -1, -1, -1,  1,  1,  1,  1, -1, -1,  1,  0, -1, -1,
        -1,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, -1, -1,  1,  1, -1, -1, -1],
       [ 1,  0, -1,  1,  1, -1, -1,  1,  1,  1,  1, -1, -1,  1,  1, -1,  1,
         1,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, -1, -1,  1,  1,  0,  1, -1],
       [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1, -1, -1, -1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, -1, -1,
        -1,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1, -1, -1, -1,  1,  1, -1, -1, -1],
       [ 1,  1, -1,  1,  1, -1,  0, -1,  1,  1,  1, -1,  1,  1,  0,  1,  1,
         1,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1, -1, -1,  1,  1,  1, -1,  1, -1]])
In [282]:
```

The pastebin `tensorflow` code:

```
target.append(row.pop(30))
data.append(np.asarray(row, dtype=features_dtype))


  target = np.array(target, dtype=target_dtype)
  data = np.array(data)
  return Dataset(data=data, target=target)
```

removes the last item in the `row` and puts into `target`, and rest into `data`.

With my `numpy` array you'd get the same effect with

```
 result = data[:,-1]
 data = data[:,;-1]
```

this splits off the last column of the 31 column array.

Comment: Sure, that's cool... but thing is the pastebin loads fine with OP's original code too.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your work done efficiently and with ease if you use pandas (python library widely used for data manipulation). Here is the link for official pandas documentation:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/

Note: Pandas has built-in functions for reading csv files. You can also use 'tolist' method to get a list of data in your csv easily and then manipulate it.